# Возврат русского имени файла в ответе HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, webapi

webApi формирует файл и отправляет его следующим способом:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
string contenttype = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contenttype);
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;   
return response;
```

filename содержит имя файла написанное кириллицей. В результате мне приходит кракозябра вместо имени файла.

> attachment;filename="=?utf-8?B?0KPQstC10LTQvtC80LvQtdC90LjQtSDRgSDRgNGD0YHRgdC60LjQvNC4INCx0YPQutCy0LDQvNC4Lnhsc3g=?="

Можно ли как-то отправить имя файла читаемое или надо конвертировать уже на принимающей стороне?

Comment: `или надо конвертировать уже на принимающей стороне?` надо, да. `Уведомление с русскими буквами.xlsx` Если это браузер, то он сам с этим автоматически прекрасно справится.

Comment: Надо проверить на vue... может там что не так... браузер отдает кракозябры...

Comment: `0KPQstC10LTQvtC80LvQtdC90LjQtSDRgSDRgNGD0YHRgdC60LjQvNC4INCx0YPQutCy0LDQvNC4Lnhsc3g=` это правильно закодированное имя файла по спецификации HTTP, Base64 кодировка.

Comment: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2543744/5045688), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68587104/5045688). Дополнительно задайте свойство [FileNameStar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.contentdispositionheadervalue.filenamestar?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Как это работает: [RFC-6266 - Use of the Content-Disposition Header Field in the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6266).